# Not able to display json data on jsp with ajax and struts2 integration

Tags: ajax, struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-json-plugin, struts2-jquery-plugin

I not able to display the json data on jsp. 
When i checked for console logs in browser I am able to see the json content in console. 
Can anyone help me with ajax code to display the data?

**Web.xml** content

```
<struts> 
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" /> 
<package name="default" extends="json-default" namespace="/">       
<action name="getCronDetails" class="myaction">             
<result name="SUCCESS">/schedule.jsp</result>       
</action>   
</package> 
</struts>
```

Action class content:

```
List<emp> myList=new ArrayList<emp>() ;
//setter getter method for myList 

public String getCronDetails (){        
myList = fetchData() ;          
return "SUCCESS"; 
}
```

I want to display `myList` in table format which is of type emp. 
Can any one help me with ajax code?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're actually having a problem with since you don't include any of your JS code you're using to try to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using jQuery for the ajax calls.
In the html you need an element to trigger to call, as an example I am using a button.

The button should trigger the js function that calls the action.
In the example I have added callbacks for disabeling the button and showing a spinner (I left them commented, as the spinner is not there).

You get the ajax response in the `response` variable. After you get the response you can update the DOM with it's contents.

```js
$(document).ready({
 
 $("#getButton").click(function(event){
  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getCronDetails",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function(){
       //Disable send button and start a spinner
        },
        success: function(response, status, jqXHR){
         //console.log("Ajax Success!");
         if(typeof response !== 'object'){
          response = JSON.parse(response);
      }
         //doSomethingWithThe(response);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, status, error){
         //console.log('Ajax Error');
         //showError('Ajax Error: ' + error );
        },
        complete: function(){
         //Enable Submit Button and stop spinner
        }

  });
 
 
 });
 

});
```

```html
...
<body>
 <!-- A button to trigger the ajax call -->
 <button id="getButton">Get Cron Details</button>
 
 <!-- Include jQuery -->
 <script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
...
```